# Paypal : "The network connection was lost."

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal (MPL) iOS SDK. Since few days, while initializing Paypal instance, I am getting **error**

> "The network connection was lost.".

Till then it was working fine.

My code for initialising is like below in AppDelegate:

```
[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"AppID" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your Internet Connection working fine?

Comment: I am also facing same problem today. any solution?

Comment: @Amanpreet : my internet connection is working properly throughout the application. This pop up comes only when i initialize Paypal.